# Why git repack fails in `filter-repo`?

Tags: git

I have a repo where `git fsck --strict --full` returns `0` and
I now add a file `.gitattributes` to every commit with `git filter-repo` [script here](https://gist.github.com/gabyx/477d221381b577a814957cc5ff7d5ffc) or here the equival. command:

```sh
FILTER_BRANCH_SQUELCH_WARNING=1 \
    git filter-branch -f \
    --index-filter \
    "cp -f '$outDir/.gitattributes' .gitattributes && git add .gitattributes" \
    --tag-name-filter cat \
    --prune-empty -- --all
```

Which fails with

```
Repacking your repo and cleaning out old unneeded objects
Counting objects: 100% (571811/571811), done.
Delta compression using up to 14 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (108091/108091), done.
error: bad packed object CRC for e9975de53768c33397b84bdad69b9c3e7a0aaba6
error: bad packed object CRC for e9975de53768c33397b84bdad69b9c3e7a0aaba6
fatal: packed object e9975de
```

I am completely out of any hope here, I dont know what I am doing wrong? if the disk would be full, wouldn't there be another failure, and I checked I have enought space, also on the system...?

**Note:** I am on ubuntu:focal with git build 2.27.0 on a Virtual Box 6.1 with a Windows Host, with a SSD where the repo is in a
`.vdi` Image.

**Update:** Sometimes it fails, and sometimes it passes ???

Comment: Might it be related with a wrong depencency for git`?  zlib or so?

Comment: two things: first, this doesn't look like heisenbug territory, I suspect you're facing hardware trouble; second, that filter-branch isn't as inefficient as the ones in the filter-repo readme, but it's pretty bad. Add the gitattributes file once, get its hash with `git rev-parse :.gitattributes`, your index filter is ```git update-index cacheinfo 100644,$itshash,.gitattributes```.

Comment: so, your saying git filter-repo is less efficient (I experienced it otherway round). But as I now understand, adding it once to the object store and later only updating the index should be better indeed

Comment: No, I'm saying filter-repo's readme doesn't just have its thumb on the scale, it's pretty much parked its rear on it.

Comment: Heisenbug whatever, I changed the location of the drive for the repo, startet with a fresh one, which has no `fsck` failure. After the rewrite, it fails...
either its related to the fact that I am using VirtualBox , but otherwise I really have noo clue... it cant be a bug in git?, but maybe in filter-repo... (but I had the same troubles with filter-branch as well)

Comment: Eliminate virtualbox from the setup and see if it still happens.

Comment: Thats the exact next thing I am gonna do

Answer (score 0):

You might try again with Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), since "[`git repack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1fdedb7c7d60f48dcfab875f9f2027ae2d1b777c/Documentation/git-repack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack))</sup> machinery learns to pay attention to the `--filter=` option.

The `index-filter` of `git filter-branch` might trigger a filter on `git repack` which should be better processed, now that `git repack` officially support filters.

See [commit 9b96046](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b96046b9239589756cde8fbcbafe05ac7ec4611), [commit 71c5aec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/71c5aec1f54eba5a2856f72d85823af64e5deb34), [commit 1cd43a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cd43a9ed96831b983fada37a71daacb6be373dc), [commit 48a9b67](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48a9b67b4301083d0820e90afef208ed1436298f), [commit 0e4747e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e4747ec8b5558e7106146fd37501649f577bcfa), [commit be315e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be315e9a3fe070af60821f01c2bc508457d2c1b2), [commit ff8504e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff8504e4ec5628edddb67f989256b7f2aea6c45d), [commit 66589f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66589f89ab8bf19f79fa9e9ec156bce43ed70e53), [commit 6cfcabf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cfcabfb9f60369f6fb4d24465a7c98b1d90b34b) (02 Oct 2023) by [Christian Couder (`chriscool`)](https://github.com/chriscool).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1fdedb7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fdedb7c7d60f48dcfab875f9f2027ae2d1b777c), 10 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`repack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48a9b67b4301083d0820e90afef208ed1436298f): add `--filter=<filter-spec>` option
>
> <sup>Helped-by: Taylor Blau</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: John Cai</sup>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christian Couder</sup>

> This new option puts the objects specified by `<filter-spec>` into a separate packfile.
>
> This could be useful if, for example, some blobs take up a lot of precious space on fast storage while they are rarely accessed.
> It could make sense to move them into a separate cheaper, though slower, storage.
>
> It's possible to find which new packfile contains the filtered out objects using one of the following:
>
> - [`git verify-pack -v ...`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/48a9b67b4301083d0820e90afef208ed1436298f/Documentation/git-verify-pack.txt#L26)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-verify-pack#Documentation/git-verify-pack.txt--v))</sup>,
> - `test-tool find-pack ...`, which a previous commit added,
> - `--filter-to=<dir>`, which a following commit will add to specify where the pack containing the filtered out objects will be.
>
> This feature is implemented by running [`git pack-objects`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/48a9b67b4301083d0820e90afef208ed1436298f/Documentation/git-pack-objects.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-objects))</sup> twice in a row.
> The first command is run with `--filter=<filter-spec>`, using the specified filter.
> It packs objects while omitting the objects specified by the filter.
> Then another `git pack-objects` command is launched using `--stdin-packs`.
> We pass it all the previously existing packs into its stdin, so that it will pack all the objects in the previously existing packs.
> But we also pass into its stdin, the pack created by the previous [`git pack-objects --filter=<filter-spec>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/48a9b67b4301083d0820e90afef208ed1436298f/Documentation/git-pack-objects.txt#L298)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-objects#Documentation/git-pack-objects.txt---filterltfilter-specgt))</sup> command as well as the kept packs, all prefixed with '^', so that the objects in these packs will be omitted from the resulting pack.
> The result is that only the objects filtered out by the first `git pack-objects` command are in the pack resulting from the second `git pack-objects` command.
>
> As the interactions with kept packs are a bit tricky, a few related tests are added.

`git repack` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/48a9b67b4301083d0820e90afef208ed1436298f/Documentation/git-repack.txt#L146-L157):

> ### `--filter=<filter-spec>`
>
> Remove objects matching the filter specification from the
> resulting packfile and put them into a separate packfile.
>
> Note
> that objects used in the working directory are not filtered
> out. So for the split to fully work, it's best to perform it
> in a bare repo and to use the `-a` and `-d` options along with
> this option.
>
> Also `--no-write-bitmap-index` (or the
> `repack.writebitmaps` config option set to `false`) should be
> used otherwise writing bitmap index will fail, as it supposes
> a single packfile containing all the objects. See
> [`git rev-list`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-rev-list) for valid `<filter-spec>` forms.

And:

> ### [`gc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cd43a9ed96831b983fada37a71daacb6be373dc): add `gc.repackFilter` config option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christian Couder</sup>

> A previous commit has implemented [`git repack --filter=<filter-spec>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1cd43a9ed96831b983fada37a71daacb6be373dc/Documentation/git-repack.txt#L146)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack#Documentation/git-repack.txt---filterltfilter-specgt))</sup> to allow users to filter out some objects from the main pack and move them into a new different pack.
>
> Users might want to perform such a cleanup regularly at the same time as they perform other repacks and cleanups, so as part of [`git gc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1cd43a9ed96831b983fada37a71daacb6be373dc/Documentation/git-gc.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))</sup>.
>
> Let's allow them to configure a `<filter-spec>` for that purpose using a new gc.repackFilter config option.
>
> Now when `git gc` will perform a repack with a `<filter-spec>` configured through this option and not empty, the repack process will be passed a corresponding `--filter=<filter-spec>` argument.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1cd43a9ed96831b983fada37a71daacb6be373dc/Documentation/config/gc.txt#L148-L152):

> ### `gc.repackFilter`
>
> When repacking, use the specified filter to move certain
> objects into a separate packfile.  See the
> `--filter=<filter-spec>` option of [`git repack`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack).