# Can you convert an existing git repository to be a "blobless" one?

Tags: git, git-clone

Today, git offers "partial clone" options that enable downloading the commits and trees of a repository, while allowing blobs to be downloaded on-demand, saving network bandwidth and disk space.

This can be enabled during the initial `git clone` by passing `--filter=blob:none`. However, is there a way to convert an already existing local repository to the "blobless" format? This should save some disk space by deleting any local blobs known to be available from the
"promisor" remote.

Comment: Would locally cloning be an option for you? (e.g. `git clone --filter=blob:none /path/to/full/repo.git /path/to/blobless.git`)

Comment: @knittl I think that would result in the original path being the promisor remote for the newly cloned one, so I couldn't delete the original? Or maybe I could fix that up after the fact.

Comment: Nathan, afterwards, change the URL of the `origin` remote repository to point to the original one.

Comment: There's no existing, user-oriented, convenient way. The method @knittl outlined will work. Be aware that partial clone itself is still not really ready for The Masses to use: you'll run into sharp edges now and then.

Answer (score 2):

While I'm not aware of a dedicated in-place command, you can still perform a local cloning and then replace your original folder with the blobless copy.
(solution inspired by [knittl](/users/112968/knittl) [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68811902/can-you-convert-an-existing-git-repository-to-be-a-blobless-one#comment121610577_68811902))

```sh
# If it's your first time, you'd need to enable filtering locally.
git config --global uploadpack.allowFilter true

# Filter your existing repo into a new one.
# The `file://` protocol followed by a full path is required.
git clone --filter=blob:none file:///full_path_to_existing_repo/.git path_to_new_blobless_copy

# Reconfigure the origin of your new repo.
# You can retrieve it with `git remote -v` in your existing repo.
cd path_to_new_blobless_copy
git remote set-url origin remote_path_to_origin.git
cd -

# Replace your existing repo with the new one.
# Destructive operation that will free up the space of the blobs.
# But will also destroy your local stashes, branches and tags that you didn't clone!
rm -rf /full_path_to_existing_repo
mv path_to_new_blobless_copy /full_path_to_existing_repo
```

Answer (score 2):

I believe the only difference in the `.git/config` between a clone with and without `--filter=blob:none` is the following configuration:

```
...
[remote "origin"] # or whatever your remote is named
promisor = true
partialclonefilter = blob:none
...
```

Which you can change with these commands:

```
# change <origin> to the name of your remote
git config remote.origin.promisor true
git config remote.origin.partialclonefilter blob:none
```

According to the [docs](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-remoteltnamegtpartialclonefilter) changing this only affects fetches of new commits, but I believe `git gc --prune=now` should clean the unnecessary objects.

Comment: Didn't work. Using git@github.com:baumgarr/nixnote2.git as a test repo, `du -sk .` actually INCREASED from 75428 to 75500.    `--aggressive` only reduced it to 67832, whereas a true blobless clone was 13612.

Comment: I wonder what would happen if one unpacked everything and deleted all the blobs (maybe trees too?). I didn't compare space savings, but my client redownloaded branch blobs after I used `--aggressive`.

Answer (score 1):

First ensure that all blobs in the repo exist on the remote by pushing any commits.

```
upstream=origin
gitdir=$(realpath $(git rev-parse --git-dir))

mv "$gitdir"/objects "$gitdir"/objects.bak  # Create backup
mkdir "$gitdir"/objects  # Required else git thinks its not a repository

# Tell git this repo is blobless
git config remote."$upstream".promisor true
git config remote."$upstream".partialclonefilter blob:none

# Fetch branches, trees, and tags
git fetch --refetch --tags --no-auto-gc 

# Now fetch the objects reachable from HEAD:
git fetch-pack --refetch --keep --quiet git@github.com:user/repo.git  $(git rev-list --missing=allow-promisor --objects HEAD | cut -c 1-40) > /dev/null

git fsck --full && echo "Remember to: rm -rf "$gitdir"/objects.bak"
```

---

Regarding local stashes and tags (if you have any, the final `git fsck --full` will complain if you do):

- Create a pack of local-only objects using [`git-pack-objects`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-pack-objects), then restore this single manually-created pack
- Get hashes of stashes:

  ```
  git for-each-ref refs/stash --format='%(objectname)'
  ```
- Get hashes of annotated tags:

  ```
  git for-each-ref --format="%(if:equals=tag)%(objecttype)%(then)%(objectname)%(else)%(end)" --sort=taggerdate refs/tags
  ```
- Make the above even smaller by getting the objects in X but not in the parent

  ```
  git rev-list --objects 68268d5 '^68268d5^^'
  ```

  (The first `^` means "not" and the `^^` means parent)

Thanks to [Oded Niv's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76043016/5353461) for the config tips.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a way to convert an already existing local repository to the "blobless" format?

Git 2.43 (Q4 2023) might offer a different approach, since "[`git repack`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/1fdedb7c7d60f48dcfab875f9f2027ae2d1b777c/Documentation/git-repack.txt)"<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack))</sup> machinery learns to pay attention to the `--filter-to=` option.

See [commit 9b96046](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b96046b9239589756cde8fbcbafe05ac7ec4611), [commit 71c5aec](https://github.com/git/git/commit/71c5aec1f54eba5a2856f72d85823af64e5deb34), [commit 1cd43a9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1cd43a9ed96831b983fada37a71daacb6be373dc), [commit 48a9b67](https://github.com/git/git/commit/48a9b67b4301083d0820e90afef208ed1436298f), [commit 0e4747e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0e4747ec8b5558e7106146fd37501649f577bcfa), [commit be315e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/be315e9a3fe070af60821f01c2bc508457d2c1b2), [commit ff8504e](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ff8504e4ec5628edddb67f989256b7f2aea6c45d), [commit 66589f8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/66589f89ab8bf19f79fa9e9ec156bce43ed70e53), [commit 6cfcabf](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cfcabfb9f60369f6fb4d24465a7c98b1d90b34b) (02 Oct 2023) by [Christian Couder (`chriscool`)](https://github.com/chriscool).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 1fdedb7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1fdedb7c7d60f48dcfab875f9f2027ae2d1b777c), 10 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`repack`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/71c5aec1f54eba5a2856f72d85823af64e5deb34): implement `--filter-to` for storing filtered out objects
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christian Couder</sup>

> A [previous commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275967/6309) has implemented [`git repack --filter=<filter-spec>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/71c5aec1f54eba5a2856f72d85823af64e5deb34/Documentation/git-repack.txt#L146)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack#Documentation/git-repack.txt---filterltfilter-specgt))</sup> to allow users to filter out some objects from the main pack and move them into a new different pack.
>
> It would be nice if this new different pack could be created in a different directory than the regular pack.
> **This would make it possible to move large blobs into a pack on a different kind of storage, for example cheaper storage**.
>
> Even in a different directory, this pack can be accessible if, for example, the Git alternates mechanism is used to point to it.
> In fact not using the Git alternates mechanism can corrupt a repo as the generated pack containing the filtered objects might not be accessible from the repo any more.
> So setting up the Git alternates mechanism should be done before using this feature if the user wants the repo to be fully usable while this feature is used.
>
> In some cases, like when a repo has just been cloned or when there is no other activity in the repo, it's Ok to setup the Git alternates mechanism afterwards though.
> It's also Ok to just inspect the generated packfile containing the filtered objects and then just move it into the '.git/objects/pack/' directory manually.
> That's why it's not necessary for this command to check that the Git alternates mechanism has been already setup.
>
> While at it, as an example to show that `--filter` and `--filter-to` work well with other options, let's also add a test to check that these options work well with `--max-pack-size`.

`git repack` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/71c5aec1f54eba5a2856f72d85823af64e5deb34/Documentation/git-repack.txt#L158-L168):

> ### `--filter-to=<dir>`
>
> Write the pack containing filtered out objects to the
> directory `<dir>`. Only useful with `--filter`.
>
> **This can be
> used for putting the pack on a separate object directory that
> is accessed through the Git alternates mechanism**.
>
> **WARNING:**
> If the packfile containing the filtered out objects is not
> accessible, the repo can become corrupt as it might not be
> possible to access the objects in that packfile. See the
> `objects` and `objects/info/alternates` sections of
> linkgit:gitrepository-layout[5].

And:

> ### [`gc`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9b96046b9239589756cde8fbcbafe05ac7ec4611): add `gc.repackFilterTo` config option
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Christian Couder</sup>

> A [previous commit](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77275967/6309) implemented the `gc.repackFilter` config option to specify a filter that should be used by [`git gc`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9b96046b9239589756cde8fbcbafe05ac7ec4611/Documentation/git-gc.txt)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc))</sup> when performing repacks.
>
> Another previous commit has implemented [`git repack --filter-to=<dir>`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9b96046b9239589756cde8fbcbafe05ac7ec4611/Documentation/git-repack.txt#L158)<sup>([man](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-repack#Documentation/git-repack.txt---filter-toltdirgt))</sup> to specify the location of the packfile containing filtered out objects when using a filter.
>
> Let's implement the `gc.repackFilterTo` config option to specify that location in the config when `gc.repackFilter` is used.
>
> Now when `git gc` will perform a repack with a `<dir>` configured through this option and not empty, the repack process will be passed a corresponding `--filter-to=<dir>` argument.

`git config` now includes in its [man page](https://github.com/git/git/blob/9b96046b9239589756cde8fbcbafe05ac7ec4611/Documentation/config/gc.txt#L153-L163):

> ### `gc.repackFilterTo`
>
> When repacking and using a filter, see `gc.repackFilter`, the
> specified location will be used to create the packfile
> containing the filtered out objects.
>
> **WARNING:** The
> specified location should be accessible, using for example the
> Git alternates mechanism, otherwise the repo could be
> considered corrupt by Git as it migh not be able to access the
> objects in that packfile.